# CloudSQL docker container fails to connect to sql instance for a while then connects in k8s

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect to my GCP Sql instance using a docker cloud-sql container. I also have a service that depends on cloudsql to connect to the database in GKE. Together, these two create a pod.

The connection always seems to fail about 3 or 4 times and then connects successfully. this happens every time want to deploy a new version of my service by creating an updated kubernetes pod.

My kubernetes deployment that describe this code is:

```
...

- name: cloudsql-proxy
  image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.12
  command:
    - /cloud_sql_proxy
    - -instances=my-project:europe-west1:my-instance=tcp:5432
    - -credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json

...
```

I expect cloud-sql to connect immediately to my instance but I get this error a couple of times on my logs

```
couldn't connect to "my-project:europe-west1:my-instance": Post https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/my-project/instances/my-instance/createEphemeral?alt=json&prettyPrint=false: oauth2: cannot fetch token: Post https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

Comment: This error indicates an overloaded pod or a slow network startup time. Since you are connecting to a Google OAuth endpoint, I will rule out the other side being the problem.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley What do you mean an overloaded pod?

Comment: The error means that the network response is very slow. If you have a pod that was overloaded (hitting memory limits, CPU at 100%, etc) network response can start failing.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I think the issue could be my kubernetes cluster is overloaded when I restart all services running on my cluster. I will try to replicate this and test.

Comment: Found it. I was doing an update of my kubernetes version on my nodes. During the update, CPU usage on one of the nodes went up to 100% where I presume the pod had been scheduled. If this sounds acceptable I will add this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates an overloaded pod or a slow network startup time. Since you are connecting to a Google OAuth endpoint, I will rule out the other side being the problem.

If you have the cluster or a pod is overloaded (hitting memory limits, CPU at 100%, etc) network response can start failing.

Comment: Thanks. CPU usage on my pod was at 100% which led to a TCP handshake timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Add option `--dir=/cloudsql` after `- /cloud_sql_proxy`

```
  - name: cloudsql-proxy
    image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.14
    command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy",
                "--dir=/cloudsql",
                "-instances=my-project:europe-west1:my-instance=tcp:3306",
                # If running on a VPC, the Cloud SQL proxy can connect via Private IP. See:
                # https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip for more info.
                # "-ip_address_types=PRIVATE",
                "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"]
    # [START cloudsql_security_context]
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 2  # non-root user
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
    # [END cloudsql_security_context]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
      mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
      readOnly: true
    - name: cloudsql
      mountPath: /cloudsql
  # [END proxy_container]
  # [START volumes]
  volumes:
  - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
    secret:
      secretName: cloudsql-instance-credentials
  - name: cloudsql
    emptyDir:
  # [END volumes]
```

Comment: How does adding `--dir=/cloudsql` fix the issue?

Comment: The “/cloudsql” directory is mounted as a Filesystem in Userspace, or FUSE, by Cloud SQL Proxy. You can find more details here https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth require using refresh tokens to acquire new access tokens as they have limited lifetimes to enhance security. A refresh token will allow your application access Cloud SQL.
Please create a new token, automatically invalidates the oldest token.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer in how this relates to "TLS handshake timeout"? In the case of SQL Proxy, it is handling the issuance of service account access tokens with the metadata server.